# Did Golda Meir make this quote about curfews for women?

Tags: quotes, sexual-abuse, israel

From [Why We Can’t Stay Silent on Germany’s Mass Sex Assaults](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2016/01/08/why-we-can-t-stay-silent-on-germany-s-mass-sex-assaults.html)

> Former Israeli prime minster Golda Meir may have done and said many
>   things people disagree with, but one of her stances is difficult to
>   argue with. When there was an outbreak of nighttime assaults against
>   women in Israel, a minister in the cabinet suggested a curfew to keep
>   women in after dark. “But it’s the men who are attacking the women,”
>   she retorted. “If there’s to be a curfew, let the men stay at home,
>   not the women.”

There's a link to [Selected Quotes from Golda Meir](https://www.msudenver.edu/golda/goldameir/goldaquotes/), which has

> 22) When there was an outbreak in assaults against women at night, a
>   minister in the cabinet suggested a curfew to keep women in after
>   dark. But it’s the men who are attacking the women, Golda responded.
>   If there’s to be a curfew, let the men stay at home, not the women.

At the bottom is

> These quotes are drawn from the sources noted in the bibliography and
>   from a number of books compiling quotations.

The bibliography is on this [page](https://www.msudenver.edu/golda/goldameir/goldabibliography/), but it may not be in them if it's from a book compiling quotations.

The quote isn't listed in [Wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Golda_Meir).

Did she make the above quote about curfews?

Comment: I found this listed as being from the the 1970s in the New York Times, but no bibliography... http://www.nytimes.com/learning/general/onthisday/bday/0503.html Maybe that will help some.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Menachem Meir, Golda's son, repeated it on an interview for Israel Today ([Hebrew link](http://www.israelhayom.co.il/article/114247)).

> . בסוף 1949 התרחש רצח נורא בגן מאיר בתל אביב, זה היה יוצא דופן אז.
>   בישיבת הממשלה שר הדתות, הרב פישמן, הציע שיוטל עוצר על נשים לצאת מהבית
>   בשעות הערב. אז אמי קמה ואמרה: בדיוק להפך, את העוצר צריך להטיל על
>   הגברים

My translation:

> At the end of 1949 a horrible murder occurred in Meir Garden in Tel
>   Aviv, it was extraordinary then. In a government meeting the minister
>   of religion, Rabbi Fishman, suggested laying a curfew on women, so
>   they won't go out in the evening. Mother stood up and said, on the
>   contrary, the curfew should be laid on men.

Comment: An older, English-language link https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/culture/.premium-israeli-political-legends-hit-the-small-screen-1.5280420

Answer (score 2):

A [Hebrew blogger](https://zvitriger.wordpress.com/2004/10/18/%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%94-%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%A0%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9F/) claims this originates from an interview with Oriana Fallaci, to Ms magazine in 1973. (Based on other sources - probably April 1973).

I have no reason to doubt that attribution since it is specific (to a certain magazine and year), but I was not able to read the actual article and verify.

The reference adds that the original suggestion was by a religious minister which adds to the context of the comment.

Comment: Unless the source is verified, this answer should not be considered complete. Snopes has infamously cited nonexistent magazines.

Comment: Oooh, so close.... It's not on the [first page](https://www.etsy.com/no-en/listing/237762896/vintage-ms-magazine-april-1973-volume-1) of the article.

Comment: @Oddthinking you could email the seller and ask for a photo of the next page of the article?

Comment: Claim repeated here: http://jwa.org/encyclopedia/article/meir-golda but I always get suspicious when wikiquote lists the article its apparently a quote from, with many interesting things she DID say in it, but missing this particular quote ([link](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Golda_Meir))